# SSAS/SSRS, Unattached 'dimension' or Snowflake schema or Different Data sets?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssas, cube

I have designed in the previous weeks a cube in a star schema holding my information and managed to make a basic table report from it too.

But now, to make certain reports, the information held in the cube is not complete (or enough) for it. As it turns out, I have some parameters which are stored in a couple of tables which are not directly connected to the fact table, but its information is needed for some calculations in the reports.

My question is, how can I use such tables?

- Can I add those tables unattached to my SSAS cube? (Which I far as I'm concerned right now, is theoretically impossible and I'm not sure if it makes sense... I anyway tried it, but they can't be added to ).
- Or should I modify the schema to be a snowflake? (Which I too tried, but it adds the parameter tables under some other dimension -which I understand is a hierarchy but I'm not really sure how they work-).
- Or eventually, what I know believe the *reasonable* solution, is: can I have two different data sets (one being the cube, the other being the set of tables with the parameters) in my SSRS report that somehow interact with each other to produce some lovely graphics as a result.

Is the question too broad? Bear with me and I'll give more specific info, for now it seems the most specific I can get to try to make myself clear.

Comment: Can you use the parameters during ETL to 'embed' the results into your fact table? Or are these more like runtime parameters that need to be use for calculations on the fly? If you are using SSAS tabular you can use DAX to look up parameter tables on the fly

Comment: They are more like the second, yes. I would say they cannot be embedded into the fact table, or it could, but it would increase the redundancy exponentially.

Comment: I don't know if you're using SSAS tabular model but have a read of this http://www.daxpatterns.com/parameter-table/